# How can I include many coordinates on a map within a circle with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, folium, geopy

I have a list of coordinates. Can I draw on map a circle that briefly covers them? I was thinking about using the `folium` package and drawing a circle centered at the average coordinates with radius of the distance to the farthest point. However, it turns out `radius` doesn't correspond to real distance on map, so it wouldn't change accordingly when I zooming in/out.

```py
import folium
import numpy as np
from geopy.distance import geodesic

points = [(39.9756783, 116.3308383),
          (39.9756649, 116.3308749),
          (39.97564, 116.3308749),
          (39.9756533, 116.3308583),
          (39.9756316, 116.3308299)]
center = (np.mean([a for a,b in points]), np.mean([b for a,b in points]))
MAP = folium.Map(location = list(center), zoom_start = 10)
folium.CircleMarker(location = list(center), 
                    radius = max([geodesic(center,point).meters for point in points]),
                    color = '#3186cc', fill = True, fill_color = '#3186cc'
                   ).add_to(MAP)
MAP
```

When the list is too long to pinpoint every pair of coordinates, I really want to roughly illustrate the scope they fall into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`Circle()`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.Circle), which gives you the opportunity to specify the radius in meters (note that I multiply the max by 10 in order to get a larger circle).

For example:

```py
import folium
import numpy as np
from geopy.distance import geodesic

points = [(39.9756783, 116.3308383),
          (39.9756649, 116.3308749),
          (39.97564, 116.3308749),
          (39.9756533, 116.3308583),
          (39.9756316, 116.3308299)]
center = (np.mean([a for a,b in points]), np.mean([b for a,b in points]))
MAP = folium.Map(location = list(center), zoom_start = 10)

for p in points:
    folium.Marker(p).add_to(MAP)

folium.Circle(location = list(center),
                    radius = max([geodesic(center,point).meters for point in points])*10,
                    color = '#3186cc',
                    fill = True,
                    fill_color = '#3186cc').add_to(MAP)
MAP
```

and zooming in you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I had in mind.